# How to add pre-requisites for a certain capistrano task

Tags: capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I would like to add cap deploy:setup as a pre-requisite for cap deploy task. How should I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to your deploy.rb

```
before 'deploy:update', 'deploy:setup'
```